# Remove specific characters from column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to remove specific characters from a column using regexp.

As an example, I have this:

```
declare @a nvarchar(50) = '(djfhsd-kjfhksd'
select  Replace(@a, Substring(@a, PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', @a), 1), '')
```

But I want to remove just parenthesis (), spaces and dashes -
I don't have experience on regexp but I would like to remove them in one shot.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @a nvarchar(50) = '(djfhsd-kjfhksd'
Select  @a =Replace(@a,RemChar,'')
  From  (Values ('('),
                (')'),
                ('-'),
                (' ')
            ) B (RemChar)

Select @a
```

Returns

```
djfhsdkjfhksd
```

For something straight forward.  Otherwise you will need a UDF or a Cross Apply

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(YourCol,'(',''),')',''),'-',''),' ','')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, is there any other way using patindex?

Comment: @carlosm I'll take a second look

Comment: I need to put it as part of a query and return the result for each row

Comment: @carlosm Can you use a UDF?

Comment: I can use it but I want something straightforward